# SwiftUI animation

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am trying to animate a rectangle only in the x scale without modifying the height using `scaleEffect` but without any success. Does `scaleEffect` apply only to both dimension x, y or can we apply it to one dimension only? I tried to apply `scaleEffec`t (x,y) but it doesn't work.

```
Rectangle()
   .fill(Color.pink)
   .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
   .scaleEffect( self.isAnimating ?  1 : 2)
   .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1)) 
   .onAppear {
       self.isAnimating = true
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scaleEffect` with CGSize:

```
func scaleEffect(_ scale: CGSize, anchor: UnitPoint = .center) -> some View
```

which will give you the desired effect:

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.pink)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 1.0) : CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1))
    .onAppear {
        isAnimating = true
    }
```